# Artefacts in rawvideo rgb24 conversion to cfhd and prores using ffmpeg pipes

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

[image: cfhd or prores converted frame]

[image: Original Frame]

I am piping rgb24 video to ffmpeg and encoding video. I have no issues with h.264, h.265 or dnxhd.. With ProRes and cineform, I get really odd artefacts. It seems that ffmpeg (or at least the cfhd and ProRes encoders) are ignoring the rgb24 and assuming yuv or/and planar data.

```
ffmpeg  -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt  rgb24  -s 1280x720 -r 24 -i /tmp/LRVideo  -thread_queue_size 4096 -i Untitled4.wav  -c:v cfhd -quality 10 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  Untitled4.mov
```

And ffmpeg messages indicate

```
Input #0, rawvideo, from '/tmp/LRVideo':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 530841 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 1280x720, 530841 kb/s, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'Untitled4.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:52.21, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> cfhd (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov @ 0x7fecc9051e00] Using MS style video codec tag, the file may be unplayable!
Output #0, mov, to 'Untitled4.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: cfhd, yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 cfhd
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 pcm_s16le
```

Comment: Do the artefacts show when playing with ffplay?

Comment: @Gyan yes. I was able to isolate the issue. When rgb24 or argb is supplied via a pipe to ffmpeg, these problems occur. Changing the input to rgb48 or rgb64 removes the issue. Is it possible that the pipe input to cfhd and prores_ks are hard wired to be 16-bit ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be important to all those using pipes with ffmpeg. When **rgb24** or **argb** is supplied via a pipe to ffmpeg, these problems occur. Changing the input to **rgb48** or **rgb64** removes the issue.

Using **rgb48** and **rgb64** caused no issues with various presets.

This command works perfectly.

```
ffmpeg  -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt  rgb48  -s 1280x720 -r 24 -i /tmp/LRVideo  -thread_queue_size 4096 -i Untitled4.wav  -c:v cfhd -quality 10 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  Untitled4.mov
```